# Dynamically large tags$img in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I want the image I put in my `Shiny` app to occupy its entire space without overflowing. This requires the image to change its size with the window width.

For instance, let's say I have this code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$img(src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded") # The important part
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As it is, the image occupies its normal width and height, which in this case is `316x316`. I want it to occupy the entire horizontal space it has, which in this case is the width of the entire window. How can I do that? None of the little `css` I know can help (`width = "100px"` is static, and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    column(12,
           tags$img(src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded",
                    width="100%",height="600"
           ) 
    )
    # The important part
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes, `"100%` worked... I will accept your answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me.